# Importing data from a different spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm familiar with using the following to pull data in from another spreadsheet....

```
=[filename.xlsm]Sheet!A1
```

My question is, can I specify the filename in a cell (like AI) then use that cell reference in order to pull that data in...

```
A1 = filename.xlsm
```

Then the corresponding cell formula would be

```
=[AI]Sheet!A1
```

Such that if I changed the name of the file in cell A1 I would change the reference and pull data from another source? The above is just an example, it doesn't work so my question is can this be done and if so, how?

** The file that I am pulling data from may not be open at the same time **

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! Using [`Indirect()`](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) you can:

If A1 has a filename, in B1 you can put:
`=Indirect("'["&A1&"]Sheet1'!A1")`

Note: With `Indirect()`, your workbook that you're referring to has to be open, otherwise you'll see an `#REF` error.

Comment: Is there a method that would work if the file isn't open? For example, my files are being stored in Office 365/One Drive and if I open it online I won't necessarily have the other file open as well.

Comment: Hm - So, your spreadsheet that has the `Indirect()` may not be open when you open the `filename.xlsm`?  Or the other way around?

Comment: The one using Indirect() would be open, but the file I am pulling the data from may not be.

Comment: Is it a hassle/issue to have that open, when using the Excel file?  I only ask because we can probably get around the issue of having the workbook open, it might require VBA though.  (Can you edit your OP to include this point, that you may not always have the data file open?)

Comment: Edited... I am expecting other users to open it and I don't want to have to ask them to open the other file basically.

Comment: What about running/enabling macros?  If you're hesitant to ask them to open a file, how comfortable are you with having them run macros? Note also this could be a security issue, some places don't allow `.xlsm` since there's code in there.

Comment: Sorry - When you said "...don't want to have to ask them to open the other file..." - do you mean you don't want another file open at all, or you just don't want to prompt the user?  We could quickly open the file in VBA, put the data in there, paste as Values, and close the file.

Comment: My reasoning Is that I plan to share the file with them via Office 365 online and have them access it through the browser. If it's possible for VBA to open the file, pull the data then close all via the browser interface then that would be fine.

Comment: The main file will be a drop of all the data, the second file will just pull the key data from the first file and present it. It will mostly be protected as well.

Comment: My mistake, Office online won't allow a file to be opened in the browser that uses references to external files. It forces the user to download it to their desktop copy of Excel. I might have to consider an alternative solution.

Comment: In order to prevent an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you perhaps put a summary of your overall goal in the OP?

Comment: To be honest, your answer satisfies the original question. My subsequent question would best be posted in another question so as not to prolong the discussion here.